# I want to set half background using color in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.bg_color {
  width: 100vw; /* view width */
  height: 100vh; /* view height */
  padding: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 
  Create the diagonal line in the background by setting each color to take 
  up 50% of the space. Setting the break points to 49.9% and 50.1% will minimize 
  the jagged line that is created if gradient colors were to be set to 50%/50%. 
  */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, color-stop(49.9%, #000000), color-stop(50.1%, #1DA1F2));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #000000 49.9%, #1DA1F2 50.1%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #000000 49.9%, #1DA1F2 50.1%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, #000000 49.9%, #1DA1F2 50.1%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_color">
  
  <h1>Half Background</h1>
  
</div>
```

I want to set half background like this[image]

in my code, I want to add half the background using color code I have tried following the code but I can't understand how to set it properly!

Comment: Please edit your question to put your code into a snippet, including relevant HTML, so we can run it to see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @frenzin if you sort the answers by date created, you'll see that my answer was the first one. The answer that you accepted was the last one, and `khushi` simply copied my answer.

Comment: @barnee i got your answer first!!!

Comment: @frenzin than can you please select it as accepted answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you use a white overlay with a radius for the white section:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#6b43fc+0,6b4dc2+100 */
background: #6b43fc; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #6b43fc 0%, #6b4dc2 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #6b43fc 0%,#6b4dc2 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #6b43fc 0%,#6b4dc2 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6b43fc', endColorstr='#6b4dc2',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 80px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I couldn't reproduce the exact curve, but you can play around with `border-top-left-radius: H V` where H is the horizontal and the V is the vertical radius.
To learn more check out this [link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to set it via HTML - it may look like this:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-image: linear-gradient(to left, white 0%, white 100%), radial-gradient(white 60%, transparent 60%), linear-gradient(to left, red 0%, #1DA1F2 100%); background-position: 120px 193px, -30px 170px, 0; background-repeat: no-repeat"></div>
```